# Best practice to try Unix/Linux software on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, emacs

I am currently trying to download a unix/linux software and would like some advice on which to download. I am trying to find a single point of download and management of the Unix tools (emacs, Python, LaTex, C++, etc.). What would you recommend for windows users?

I have only heard of good downloading options for mac (being macport) and I am looking for something similar. I heard in macport that users have just a single set of commands for installation, they can update everything that is out of date with one command, and the whole set of tools live in one directory so they can easily remove it, move it to another computer, back it up, etc.

Comment: To be clear you want GNU/Linux tools that run on windows?

Comment: I'd start with [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)

Comment: Don't be dissuaded, but note that none of the things you've mentioned require a Unix/Linux environment. Emacs has an official Windows release, Python and C++ are programming languages with readily available interpreters and compilers, and for LaTeX there is TeX Live.  These might even be available through Microsoft's OneGet

Comment: the question is really unclear of what you are trying to achieve. Could you provide more detail on the actual problem you are trying to solve? (i.e. "write software X" or "use software X") Why do you need LaTeX and C++ and python and emacs?

Answer (score 2):

[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) is what you want.  It has all the standard unix tools and many others packaged for Windows, with a fairly easy to use GUI to select, download, install, and upgrade packages.

There's a nice, short overview of its features at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)